# Why do some classes provide a way to create compile-time objects using constant constructors, why some don't? Are there any reasons behind that?

Tags: flutter, dart

Why do some classes provide a way to create compile-time objects using constant constructors, why some don't? Are there any reasons behind that? I couldn't find anywhere that tells me that.

Like `AppBar` class, for example, doesn't allow us to create a compile-time object. While `MaterialApp` class provides us to create a compile-time object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a qualifying class can have a `const` constructor.  For example, all of the properties must be `final`.  And, the author of the class must provide a const constructor explicitly.  Some authors forget to do that.

Comment: That might be a good reason. And I have found the source code of app_bar.dart has a lot of final properties with over 2000 lines of code, for example, the `title` property, or the `backgroundColor` property, both are the final fields inside of the AppBar class. It's hard for me to find mutable properties for the sake of learning.

Comment: @NgocDat A class can provide a `const` constructor only if it's able to actually create a compile-time constant.  If construction of the object depends on calling functions (which includes calling getters and includes operators, with some exceptions) or on other things that cannot be determined at compile-time, it inherently cannot be `const`.